# How do I post data to the server without leaving the current page?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, submit

What I want is having a JavaScript function which sends a `POST` to an arbitrary site and stays the whole time on the site 'it was executed on'. It does not necessarily have to be done with a form!

I don't want to use jQuery, if possible.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can "prevent" the default behavior.

```html
<form id="myform">
    Name: <input id="name" type="text" value="onur" /><br />
    Email: <input id="email" type="text" value="onur@email.com" /><br />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">type=submit</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="form.submit()">form.submit()</button>
</form>
```

Before the `</body>` tag (or on DOM ready);

```js
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
function onSubmit(event) {
    if (event) { event.preventDefault(); }
    console.log('submitting');
    postFormData(form); // <-------- see below
}
// prevent when a submit button is clicked
form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit, false);
// prevent submit() calls by overwriting the method
form.submit = onSubmit;
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/vrnf7u4c/)

**EDIT:**
The default behavior of `form.submit()` will redirect the page to the `form.action` URL. This is an approach on how you simulate the default behavior without redirecting to another page.

And since you want to "POST" the form, here is the method (AJAX stuff):

```js
function postFormData(form) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        formData = urlEncodeFormData(form); // see below

    // set XHR headers
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // watch for state changes
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            // This is where you show a success message to the user
        }
    };
    // open and send the post request
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://myweb.com/action-target', true);
    xhr.send(formData);
}

// You could use the FormData API if the browser supports it.
// Below is somewhat alternate and should be improved to support more form element types.
function urlEncodeFormData(form) {
    var i, e, data = [];
    for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        e = form.elements[i];
        if (e.type !== 'button' && e.type !== 'submit') {
            data.push(encodeURIComponent(e.id) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(e.value)); 
        }
    }
    return data.join('&');
}
```

See:

- [MDN — Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)
- [MDN — FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)
- [Can I Use FormData?](http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData)

Answer (score 2):

Give your form an onsubmit handler that returns false. Do whatever processing you need to do in there (eg: ajax send data or what have you)

Code's untested, but here's the general idea.

```
function doFormThings() {
  //processing form here
  return false; //don't actually redirect, browser, I'm watching you
};

<form onsubmit="return doFormThings();">
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dynamically creating the form, you can create it in an iframe and submit it inside of the iframe - that way you won't leave the current page and you'll actually use normal form submit. Here is a working example:

```
function generateFormAndSubmit()
{
    // Create an input for the form
    var input = document.createElement( 'input' );
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = 'test'
    input.value = '123';

    // Create the form itself
    var form = document.createElement( 'form' );
    form.action = '/myaction';

    // Append the created input to the form
    form.appendChild( input );

    // Create the iframe that will hold the form
    var iframe = document.createElement( 'iframe' );

    // Make it offscreen, so it's not visible for the user
    iframe.style.cssText = 'width: 1px;height: 1px;position: absolute;top: -10px;left: -10px';

    // Append the iframe to our document
    document.body.appendChild( iframe );

    // Append the form to the iframe
    iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild( form );

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
}
```

You can call the submit of the form from another place, of course, like a button for an example - the iframe is yours, so you can manipulate (search for the form, modify it, submit it, etc.) it's contents at any point - no security restrictions will apply.

If you need a result of the submit, then it's a bit more complicated - first, the action of the form needs to point to the same domain. Then, if that is true, you just listen for when the iframe is loaded and read the result from it's content (either printed in the document JS or parse the DOM in some way).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have an iframe and change the form's target to post the data into it. E.g:

```
<form method='POST' target='hd-submit'>
  <input name='firstName' placeholder='First Name' type='text' />
  <input name='lastName' placeholder='Last Name' type='text' />
  <input type='submit' value='Send' />
</form>
<iframe name='hd-submit' hidden></iframe>
```